# Missing term in first-order energy of an homogeneous electron gas?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, solid-state-physics, electrons, self-energy

For jellium, the electron-electron interaction energy of a homogeneous electron gas is
$$V=\frac{e^2}{2\mathcal V}\sum_{\sigma\sigma'}\sum_{\mathbf q}\sum_{\mathbf k \mathbf k}\int\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf r\frac{e^{\mathrm i \mathbf q \cdot \mathbf r}}{r}\langle \mathrm G|a^\dagger_{\mathbf k-\mathbf q,\sigma}a^\dagger_{\mathbf k'+\mathbf q,\sigma'}a_{\mathbf k'\sigma'}a_{\mathbf k\sigma}|\mathrm G\rangle=V_{\mathbf q=0}+V_{\mathbf q\neq0},,$$
where $|\mathrm G\rangle$ is the ground state of the electron gas.

It can be show that calculating this sum for $\mathbf q=0$, gives
$$V_{\mathbf q=0}=\frac{e^2}{2\mathcal V}(\underbrace{N^2}_{\text{Hartree}}-\underbrace{N}_{???})\int\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf r\frac1{r} $$
where the term in $N^2$ (Hartree term) cancels the terms coming from the positive background. The term on $N$ is argued by Fetter-Walecka to disappear in the thermodynamic limit. The rest of the sum is the Fock exchange term.

Another way to calculate this, is to pass through the pair correlation Green's function
$$V=\frac{e^2}{2\mathcal V}\sum_{\sigma\sigma'}\int\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf r\int\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf r' \frac{1}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'|}\langle \mathrm G|\Psi^\dagger_\sigma(\mathbf r)\Psi^\dagger_{\sigma'}(\mathbf r')\Psi_{\sigma'}(\mathbf r')\Psi_{\sigma}(\mathbf r)|\mathrm G\rangle$$
$$=\frac{e^2}{2{\mathcal V}}\int\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf r\;\frac{1}{r}\left[\underbrace{N^2}_{\text{Hartree}}-\underbrace{G^2(\mathbf r)}_{=V_{\mathbf q\neq 0}}\right]$$
where $G(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')=\langle \mathrm G|\Psi^\dagger_{\sigma}(\mathbf r')\Psi_{\sigma}(\mathbf r)|\mathrm G\rangle$ (up to a volume constant, it can be calculated analytically to recover the Fock contribution as above). Again the Hartree $N^2$-term cancels the background, however there is no $N$ term! Where did it go?

Is there a difference between both approaches? Why should that $N$ term disappear in one and not in the other? It seems to be related to taking the continuous limit as the distinction between $\sum_{\mathbf q\neq0}\to \int_0^{k_{\mathrm F}}d^3q$ disappears. Is that the case?